# Does anyone know, what heuristic function is used in a*?

Tags: postgis

Does anyone know what heuristic function is used in a*?

May I change that heuristic in a* ? And how can I change it?

Here some heuristic,
Euclidean distance,
Manhattan distance,
Maximum distance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about pgRouting, by default I think it is (|dx|+|dy|)/2 . See the source code in the link:

[PgRouting source](http://download.osgeo.org/pgrouting/forum/pgrouting.postlbs.org/browser/trunk/core/src/astar_boost_wrapper.html#L70)

You can easily change the heuristic function but then you would probably have to recompile the pgRouting.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer..:)

Hwo to change and compile it?

I want to try use euclidean distance heuristic, may u give me tutorial how to change the heuristic and recompile it? :)

Comment: it depends on the OS, but you can look at this link https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/wiki/Developer---Getting-Started maybe it will help you to get started

Comment: My os is windows 7.
i did open the link, but i don't get idea how to change it..hmm

I'll try to find how to change it..if i get some news, i'll text you here..:)
If you have some news, text me in here..
hehehe, thanks mr. Mario..

Comment: Fyi, a* already use ecludian function, it was used in astar_sp function. Info from mailing list pgrouting. tq :)